# ERROR: Failed building wheel for OMSimulator (when installing using proxy network on Linux)

Tags: linux, pip, proxy, openmodelica

I am using a Linux Virtual Machine on the company network, which requires a proxy setting. I am trying to install OMSimulator through pip, using the following command. `pip3 --proxy http://proxy.company.com:<port> install OMSimulator --use-pep517` (I have hidden the proxy address)

Full Error Message:

```
Collecting OMSimulator
  Using cached OMSimulator-2.1.1.post190.tar.gz (3.2 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from OMSimulator) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->OMSimulator) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->OMSimulator) (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->OMSimulator) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->OMSimulator) (2024.2.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: OMSimulator
  Building wheel for OMSimulator (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for OMSimulator (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/OMSimulator
      error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='build.openmodelica.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /omsimulator/nightly/linux-amd64/OMSimulator-linux-amd64-v2.1.1.post190-gcfb740c.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for OMSimulator
```

Based on the error message it looks like a difficulty in connecting to build.openmodelica.org through the proxy server. Is there anything I am missing?

Note: I am able to install other packages like numpy, pandas etc with the proxy. The error is only for OMSimulator.

Comment: 1st you have to check if you can access https://build.openmodelica.org via the proxy; I just tested — I can, but I don't use your proxy.

Comment: @phd I tried the following: 
´ping build.openmodelica.org
PING omod-r630-2.ida.liu.se (192.36.54.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- omod-r630-2.ida.liu.se ping statistics ---
38 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 37869ms´

Looks like I cannot access build.openmodelica.org with my proxy.

Comment: Well, pings is not a very good test, pings are hardly could go via a proxy. Try web access. If you cannot access the site by HTTPS then it's your local network problem, and the question is offtopic at StackOverflow.